# Regular Expression for the set of all binary strings that are of even length with at least 1 zero

Tags: automata, regular-language

Also followup question is the set of all binary strings that are of even length with at least two zeros.

But for both questions I'm thinking of building my regular expression with casework, no zeroes, 1 zero, and two zeroes.

For no zeros I have: $(11)^*$

For one zero there just seems to be too many edge cases to also keep the string of even length. You have to consider the zero being at the start or somewhere in the middle or at the end. All while having the expression match any number of odd 1s.

I'm confused how to do this and looking for any insights on how to do this problem and the follow up. Thanks

Comment: You could express the string as a sequence of pairs of digits, at least one of which is `(00|01|10)`.

Comment: So `(..)*(.0|0.)(..)*` works, where `.` matches any single symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Wlog, "10" or "01" or "00" needs to be somewhere, so we start with that.

There are two cases:

Case 1: (odd number of digits)(10|01|00)(odd number of digits) 
Case 2: (even number of digits)(10|01|00)(even number of digits)

Case 1: (00|01|10|11)*(1|0)(10|01|00)(1|0)(00|01|10|11)* 
Case 2: (00|01|10|11)*(10|01|00)(00|01|10|11)*

Edit: As Karl pointed out, these two cases end up actually being the same, so you really only need case 2.

Comment: These two cases are redundant.

Comment: Oh, could you elaborate?

Comment: Well, can you think of an instance of case 1 that isn't an instance of case 2? The `10|01` already allows the 0 to occur at an even position or an odd position.

Comment: Ah, good point. I'll leave my original answer up because that's what first came to mind.

Comment: @ScottHahn Any ideas for how to work on the converse? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4768051/regular-expression-for-the-set-of-all-binary-strings-that-are-of-even-length-wit