# Regular Expression for the set of all binary strings that are of even length with at most 2 zeros

Tags: automata, regular-language

I asked the converse just recently. But now trying to understand this version..

I'm working with case work and then I will take the union of all three cases where its strings with no zeros, 1 zero, and two zeros.

For no zeros I simply have $(11)^*$

For one zero I have $1(11)^*0(11)^*|(11)^*0(11)^*1$

I'm confused about the two zeros case

Not sure if this is the right approach or if there is another method.

Comment: An alternate approach for one zero is $(11)$*$10(11)$*$|(11)$*$01(11)$*; perhaps that's more straightforward to generalize to two zeros?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the shorter $(11)^*(10|01)?(11)^*$, of course, covering zero or one zeroes.